# Error with Rtabmap and kinect

Tags: kinect, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends

I am trying to do 3D map with my kinect and RTAB-MAP, I am following this tutorial

https://code.google.com/p/rtabmap/wiki/ROS#rtabmapviz

But is for hydro and I am working with ROS fuerte. I can not get it works, I have this ERROR

```
youbot@diego-VPCEH2K1E:~$ cd ros_workspace/
youbot@diego-VPCEH2K1E:~/ros_workspace$ . setup.sh
youbot@diego-VPCEH2K1E:~/ros_workspace$ roslaunch rtabmap rgbd_mapping.launch
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is  tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion ros] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is
```

and I have no idea, do you know how do it works?

Thanks.
Regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171696/error-with-rtabmap-and-kinect/) by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe a little too late for an answer, but there is one for the sake of documentation. RTAB-Map works only with ROS Hydro and newer ROS versions. It uses catkin build system, which is maybe your problem on Fuerte. Visit https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros for installation instructions.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2014-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3